# Response.Redirect() problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle, response.redirect

Throughout my program, I always used `Response.Redirect()` method. I always assumed that whenever this method is called, the current page is terminated and the redirected page is initiated. But then, i realized that Response.Redirect() has a second parameter: `bool endResponse`. So I concluded that the page doesnt get terminated...(Correct me if I'm wrong)

But at some point I needed to use `Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","3;URL=mypage.aspx")` to delay the page redirection. But now I'm afraid the page doesn't get terminated. So I decided to use `Page.Unload` event. But I don't know how to use it.

Anyone can explain to me how to properly end the life cycle of a page?

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear to me, if you're looking for ASP.NET page life cycles please refer to this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)

Comment: Or [CodeProject article[(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle-2). FWIW, no need to use `Response.Redirect`, just link to next page, and ASP.NET will take of things.

Answer (score 0):

The page in both cases really much gets terminated.

The "default" of that 2nd value (true - default) means that the code will TERMINATE!

If you set the value = false, then the re-direct occurs, but any code you have that follows will keep running.

Thus:

```
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx")
    Debug.Print("this code will NOT run")

    or

    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx", True)    ' true is default
    Debug.Print("this code will NOT run")

    but:

    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx", False) 
    Debug.Print("this code WILL RUN - so will rest of code")
```

So, setting the value to true as you started or discovered? It will not change one thing, since that is/was the default in the first place.

So, if you use "false", then the code in that routine will continue to run until the sub exit (end sub) and then the other page will run along with its normal event cycle.

So, the true/false really just determines if you want a hard exit.

And if you have a few more lines of code that you need or want to run AFTER the response.redirect? Well, then one could:

Move the response.Redirect AFTER those lines of code, or as noted, use "false" to not terminate the execution of the code in the current sub.

so, if you include a false? Then the page re-direct occurs, but not until that sub routine in that code stub is done running.

Edit:

There seems to be some confusing over the Response.Redirect("WebForm2");

in c#, if we go to definition, we get this:
Lets look at the SECOND over-load:

[image]

NO PLACE DO we see a suggested default exists for the 2nd value.
(there is NOT a default)

And going to the def we see this:

Now how there are TWO methods (2nd is a overload)

[image]

And we can expand the 2nd one (without 2nd parameter).
We see this:

[image]

and with the overload (with 2nd value), we see this:

[image]

Once again, that 2nd parameter does NOT have a specified default.

And a simple quick test will confirm that:

```
response.Redirect("some url")
```

Or

```
response.Redirect("some url",True)
```

BOTH produce the same effect - the code stub is terminated and exits.

If one wants the code stub to run out and continue to run, then using

```
Response.Redirect("some url", false)
```

is required.

Comment: The intellisense says the default is FALSE. From intellisense //   endResponse:
        //     true to terminate the response; otherwise false. The default is false.

Comment: Intelisense from vb.net or c# does not state a default. The actual text says:>>> Redirects a client to a new URL and whether execution of the current page should terminate. endResponse: Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate. >>> -- So where in that inteli text is a default of true or false suggested, implied or actually stated (there no such suggestion or statement at all). The simple matter is if you left the 2nd parameter out, you get a terminate. And if you put in the parameter as true, then again it terminates. The 2nd overload is same as first with true.

Comment: Given that this is a overload - then of the two methods (one with a 2nd option) and one without? There is in fact no real default in the strict sense. There are two methods - one with a 2nd value and one method without. But that 2nd method when used and supplied a value of true behaves the same as the first overload. if you look REALLY close at the inteli-sense, no such default is suggested for the first overload. There is a difference between a optional parameter (with a suggested default)  and that of a different overload - this is one such case.

Comment: if you right click on the method in VS2019 and "go to definition" you can see the XML comments in the original source. That's where I got that text from - copy and pasted right from it.

Comment: Take a look at the edit and new screen caps I provided - you see no default value exists here. Well, then either the documentation is wrong, or we are both looking at two different things.  See the screen caps I provided. You can simple try the test code stubs - you see that redirect without the 2nd value, or a 2nd value of true both terminate the running code stub - so they do both the same thing.